# Edge of node relationated with himsef

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, neoeloquent

I've just started with neo4j and NeoEloquent and I cannot get the edge (there is some important information) of a node which is related to himself.

[image: Node referenced with himself]

I add this relation like this:

UserMode.php

```
 public function getTech ()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'Conoce');
    }
```

When I try to get the edge like this:

```
dump(Auth::user()->getTech()->edge(Auth::user()->getTech[0]));
```

I get this error:
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Vinelab\NeoEloquent\Eloquent\Edges\Finder::edgeFromRelationWithDirection() must be an instance of Everyman\Neo4j\Relationship, boolean given,

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear or complete enough to be sure of the right answer. Have you tried the following?

```
match (u1)-[:hasMany]->(u2) return u1,u2
```

This should return a result for the case where u1 and u2 are the same node and that node has a relationship to itself (if I remember correctly).

Otherwise, can you update your question to clarify more of the data model you're using and the Cypher you're trying to use?

Comment: The correct cypher query whould be
match (u1)-[relation:Conoce]->(u2) where ID(u1) =ID(u2) return u1,u2,relation
But I want to get the edge witn NeoEloquent, I will update my question

Comment: Sure - if you _only_ want the results where the nodes are identical; this wasn't clear from the original question. After your edit, I am not familiar with NeoEloquent, so I can't help you further.